# blogdown::serve_site() does not work under a folder of OneDrive

Tags: r, blogdown

I recently put all my files under Microsoft OneDrive Cloud folder for backup use. But I found blogdown cannot correctly build a site under such folders. Is there anyone with such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, this is not an issue on the `blogdown` side, but an issue on the `hugo` side. Now this issue should have been fixed in newer release of `hugo` than `v0.40.3`.

I tested to create a new site with RStudio's `File` menu, but `blogdown` won't find any directory under `OneDrive`, with the following  errors:

```
Error: C:\Users\zlgsa\OneDrive\Documents\test already exists but not a directory
Error: C:\Users\zlgsa\OneDrive\Documents\test already exists but not a directory
'C:\Users\zlgsa\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "test' 不是内部或外部命令，也不是可运行的程序
或批处理文件。
Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) : 
  '"C:\Users\zlgsa\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "test" --force -f toml' execution failed with error code 1
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:\Users\zlgsa\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "test" --force -f toml' had status 65535 
2: running command '"C:\Users\zlgsa\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "test" --force -f toml' had status 65535 
3: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\zlgsa\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "test" --force -f toml' had status 1
```

Then I tried to create a new site under a subfolder of `OneDrive`, but `blogdown` will say that the subfolder is not a directory, with the following messages:

```
Error: C:\Users\zlgsa\OneDrive\Documents\test already exists but not a directory
Error: C:\Users\zlgsa\OneDrive\Documents\test already exists but not a directory
'C:\Users\zlgsa\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site ".' 不是内部或外部命令，也不是可运行的程序
或批处理文件。
Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) : 
  '"C:\Users\zlgsa\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "." --force -f toml' execution failed with error code 1
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:\Users\zlgsa\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "." --force -f toml' had status 65535 
2: running command '"C:\Users\zlgsa\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "." --force -f toml' had status 65535 
3: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\zlgsa\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "." --force -f toml' had status 1
```

So it would be buggy. And see [this hogo issue](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/4079). Hopefully it will be okay after this issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I posted an Answer on a different question but thought it worth linking here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50537975/4957167

Briefly, there is a workaround to this, if you are willing / able to turn off On-demand sync of your OneDrive. I was still getting this error with Hugo 0.41, and changing the sync setting resolved the issue.

Comment: I did not get this error now. Presumably, it is possibly because that I was using the feature "always kept in this device" of `OneDrive`.