# Blogdown not able to recognize hugo.exe

Tags: r, blogdown

I am a blogdown begginner and I cant't get started due to an issue with what I think is my session unable to use the hugo.exe

In RStudio I create a new proyect and in that project I run this code which outputs this:

```
dir.create("Web")
setwd("Web")
blogdown::new_site()

The latest Hugo version is 0.38.2
trying URL 'https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/download/v0.38.2/hugo_0.38.2_Windows 64bit.zip'
length 6164680 bytes (5.9 MB)
downloaded 5.9 MB

Hugo has been installed to C:\Users\Rod\AppData\Roaming\Hugo
Error in if (grepl(r, x)) return(as.numeric_version(gsub(r, "\\1", x))) : 
argument is of length zero
```

When I try tu run again `blogdown::new_site()` it gives me this:

```
'C:\Users\Rod\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site ".' is not recognized 
as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) : 
'"C:\Users\Rod\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "." --force -f toml' 
execution failed with error code 1
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:\Users\Rod\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "." --force -f toml' had status 65535 
2: running command '"C:\Users\Rod\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "." --force -f toml' had status 65535 
3: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c 
"C:\Users\Rod\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "." --force -f toml' 
had status 1
```

I have intalled hugo by myself and use:

```
options(blogdown.hugo.dir = "C:\\Hugo\bin")
install_hugo()
```

I also have let `install_hugo()` to do default install in that bin.

I have also add it as a system environment variable but nothing seems to work.

Any help?

The weird thing is that i can do this:

```
shell(paste("C:\\Users\\Rod\\AppData\\Roaming\\Hugo\\hugo.exe", 'version'))

Hugo Static Site Generator v0.38.2 windows/amd64 BuildDate: 2018-04- 
09T08:17:46Z
```

EDIT:
By reinstalling everything and running it again in a new proyect and an empty dir, `new_page()` created all files but gave me this, but I suspect is the same issue:

```
blogdown::new_site()
trying URL 'https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium-theme/archive/master.zip'
Content length 119078 bytes (116 KB)
downloaded 116 KB

Rendering content/post/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown.Rmd
The system cannot find the path specified.

Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) : 
'"C:\Users\Rod\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -b / -D -F -d "public" -t hugo-lithium-theme' execution failed with error code 1
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:\Users\Rod\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -b / -D -F -d "public" -t hugo-lithium-theme' had status 65535 
2: running command '"C:\Users\Rod\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -b / -D -F -d "public" -t hugo-lithium-theme' had status 65535 
3: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\Rod\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -b / -D -F -d "public" -t hugo-lithium-theme' had status 1
```

`sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] blogdown_0.5.15

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] httr_1.3.1      compiler_3.4.4  bookdown_0.7   
[4] R6_2.2.2        tools_3.4.4     withr_2.1.2    
[7] curl_3.2        yaml_2.1.18     memoise_1.1.0  
[10] knitr_1.20      git2r_0.21.0    xfun_0.1       
[13] digest_0.6.15   devtools_1.13.5
```

Comment: Does `system2("C:\\Users\\Rod\\AppData\\Roaming\\Hugo\\hugo.exe", 'version')` work? And how about ` `system2('"C:\\Users\\Rod\\AppData\\Roaming\\Hugo\\hugo.exe"', 'version')`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The first one didn't do anything and the second one gave me warning: `Warning message:
running command '"\"C:\Users\Rod\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe\"" version' had status 127 `

Comment: Does the executable actually exist and is it executable? `file_test("-e", "C:\\Users\\Rod\\AppData\\Roaming\\Hugo\\hugo.exe")`

Comment: It shows me this: `Error in file_test("-e", "C:\\Users\\Rod\\AppData\\Roaming\\Hugo\\hugo.exe") : 
  test '-e' is not available.` I am sure the exe exist in the dir

Comment: Sorry I meant `-x` instead of `-e`

Comment: with `-e` it shows me this:   `C:\\Users\\Rod\\AppData\\Roaming\\Hugo\\hugo.exe 
                                            TRUE `

Comment: How about `shell('"C:\\Users\\Rod\\AppData\\Roaming\\Hugo\\hugo.exe" version')`?

Comment: it shows me this: 
`shell(paste("C:\\Users\\Rod\\AppData\\Roaming\\Hugo\\hugo.exe", 'version'))

Hugo Static Site Generator v0.38.2 windows/amd64 BuildDate: 2018-04- 
09T08:17:46Z`

Comment: You didn't run the exact code in my previous reply.

Comment: This gives me this output:  `shell('"C:\\Users\\Rod\\AppData\\Roaming\\Hugo\\hugo.exe" version')
Hugo Static Site Generator v0.38.2 windows/amd64 BuildDate: 2018-04-09T08:17:46Z`

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error if you are using OneDrive, and if OneDrive is in "Files on demand" cloud sync mode. Blogdown inherits this from Hugo, which is itself inheriting the behaviour from Go. For the full details, see this Hugo issue discussion:

https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/4079

The suggestion on there is that this will be fixed in a forthcoming Go update, which will presumably filter through into Hugo and hence Blogdown in due course.

In the meantime, if you are using OneDrive, the option that worked for me was to switch it out of 'Files On Demand' syncing mode. To do that, open OneDrive settings, go to the settings tab, and there should be a checkbox for Files on demand. If you uncheck that, it will download all files, and then Go will be able to see the folders as real folders.